# Is there a way to set the starting position of the virtual scene in Android AR emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, arcore

Currently looking to automate an AR Android application and discovered [Android AR emulator](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/emulator?hl=ja). Currently before we start a test we have to position the camera manually using a combination of keyboard and mouse movements to focus on the wall image before we can start our Appium tests.

Is there a way for use to set the position automatically when we start our Appium tests? We have also explored the [Emulator Console commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console) but have not found a way to input X, Y and Z coordinates.

Comment: Just checking that reading the sensor values from the Emulator Console and then setting the [virtual sensors](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#extended) when the emulator is in the correction AR location isn't sufficient.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Correct, the Rotate and Position tabs would be what would help but there doesn't seem to be a way using the Emulator Console commands